# Is it somehow possible to create VS Code extension using Xtext Fat Jar language server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, xtext, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol, fatjar

I'm trying to create VS Code extension out of the FatJar language server created by Xtext. I saw the example project also (https://github.com/itemis/xtext-languageserver-example) but there is just an example using reference to parent xtext project located in the same repository. Is it possible to take language server directly from local jar (e.g. located in directory /server directly in vscode extension project) ?

Comment: i dont get your question: you can package your stuff howecer you like it.

Comment: Yes of course. I mean if there is any example of creating extension for VS code using fat jar ? I didnt found any. Or do you know what should I do in order to create such extension ?

Comment: I don’t understand. In the Xtext wizard you can choose to create fat jar. Simply package it to the extension and go for it

Comment: I'm searching for the example of "package it to the extension"

Comment: There is no example but it’s trivial so I don’t get your problem

Comment: I dont know how to run the server, because I have problem with running  java -jar server.jar command, as terminal in VS Code doesnt know about java, even when I removed the default terminal and used the system terminal and set also java.home setting.

Comment: Well do something like the bat file gradle creates in the example

Comment: What is necessary to do in VS Code to enable java in terminal ? I'm trying to do that even not using fat jar, but standard executable script with dependencies ... but still doesnt work at all.

Comment: I don’t know. On all machines I worked with it works. So the script e.g. gradle creates works neither ?

Comment: No .. but it's not a problem of the script but probably of some settings of the VS Code.

Comment: i cannot follow you. vscode calls the script

Comment: Yes I know .. anyway thanks a lot @Christian

Comment: any you dont get any error messages in vscode?

Comment: Just that java wasnt found on specified path and therefore language server wasnt started. But java actualy is on specified path .. but vs code terminal dont see it somehow. I cannot run any java command from code and also from vs code terminal itself.

Comment: but how are terminal and extension related?

Comment: Dont know .. I’m just mentioning that I cannot do that in terminal and also in code. Maybe it is somehow related.

Comment: I found out what was the problem. In VS Code 1.33.0 there is general problem with terminals - just sh works and a lot of commands are not available. Simply using other version makes everything working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create VS Code extension using Fat Jar Xtext language server is pretty simple. There is just need to run `java -jar ls.jar` in the code, in order to start the language server. 
There is a problem with VS Code 1.33.0, where only the `sh` terminal is available, and a lot of commands are missing (even java -jar command in code is not executed correctly)